# Jmeter report interpreting from loadosophia, Regarding Max virtual users in summary report

Tags: jmeter

I've recently started working in Jmeter and I have run a test with 40 virtual users. I've also used loadosophia plugin that uploads results to loadosophia. But I've few doubts about numbers I've got in the summary report in loadosophia.

1. I've run with 40 virtual users with 3 seconds as ramp up period but in loadosophia report it shows Max virtual users=17 and Average virtual users = 6.5 but Transaction count is 40 which actually should be virtual users. Does this indicate there were maximum of 17 virtual users were concurrent ?
2. Test run duration it shows 3 seconds, but I can see Maximum response time is 5078 milliseconds which is(5.7 seconds) how can it be test can be completed in 3 seconds while it shows some requests took more than 5 seconds to send response? (I am assuming it is not considering ramp up period which I gave 3 seconds, Am I right?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Currently your scenario looks as:

1. Start with 1 user (which will immediately start test actions)
2. Each second add 13 users (each of them will start test actions as soon as the thread is started)
3. When thread finished it's job it exits.

So there is no way to say exactly what will be the load at the "peak" where all threads which are active at the moment are hitting the application under test.

Not too sure regarding loadosophia, but if you expect 40 concurrent virtual users the only way to reach this load is providing enough loops and adding a [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) to orchestrate the load and limit (or ramp-up) it to the value, you set in timer.

Another option is using a [Synchronizing Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) which allows to "release" threads when specified amount is reached.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for the response, the scenario is as below

start with 1 virtual user and add one thread after every 3 seconds

I am just confused with the report I got in loadosophia. 
Here is the URL for the report http://loadosophia.org/examples/126816/#tab=0

I am struggling to understand what is Max Virtual Users and Average Virtual Users

Second point is can Maximum response time be greater than Test duration? you can see it in the report.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know loadosophia specifics, one thing is obvious: total test time shouldn't be less than max response time. If you could post your .jtl file somewhere perhaps it could make things more clear. Re: Max Virtual Users - I believe that I have already provided the answer. Perhaps the following guide could be helpful: http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/147922-max-users-is-lower-than-expected